# highcharts, four aeraranges with linear gradients

Tags: css, highcharts

I'm trying to create chart in Highcharts with four arearanges and one line. I'm doing my best to get something like on image:
[arearanges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vL91.png)

I'v managed to do something like this:

```
$(function () {

var rangesHI = [
        [1246406400000, 90, 75],
        [1248998400000, 90, 75]
    ],
    rangesME = [
        [1246406400000, 75, 60],
        [1248998400000, 75, 60]
    ],
    rangesNO = [
        [1246406400000, 60, 35],
        [1248998400000, 60, 35]
    ],
    rangesLO = [
        [1246406400000, 35, 15],
        [1248998400000, 35, 15]
    ],
    averages = [
        [1246406400000, 31.5],
        [1246492800000, 32.1],
        [1246579200000, 33],
        [1246665600000, 33.8],
        [1246752000000, 31.4],
        [1246838400000, 31.3],
        [1246924800000, 38.3],
        [1247011200000, 35.4],
        [1247097600000, 36.4],
        [1247184000000, 47.7],
        [1247270400000, 47.5],
        [1247356800000, 37.6],
        [1247443200000, 47.7],
        [1247529600000, 46.8],
        [1247616000000, 47.7],
        [1247702400000, 46.3],
        [1247788800000, 47.8],
        [1247875200000, 48.1],
        [1247961600000, 57.2],
        [1248048000000, 54.4],
        [1248134400000, 53.7],
        [1248220800000, 55.7],
        [1248307200000, 54.6],
        [1248393600000, 55.3],
        [1248480000000, 45.3],
        [1248566400000, 55.8],
        [1248652800000, 65.2],
        [1248739200000, 74.8],
        [1248825600000, 44.4],
        [1248912000000, 55],
        [1248998400000, 43.6]
    ];

$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: null
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    yAxis: {
        max:90,
        min:20,
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'RH',
        data: averages,
        zIndex: 1
    }, {
        data: rangesHI,
        type: 'arearange',
        lineWidth: 0,
        fillColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgba(255,0,0, 0.2)'],
                    [1, 'rgba(255,0,0, 1)']
                ]
            },
        zIndex: 0
    }, {
        data: rangesME,
        type: 'arearange',
        lineWidth: 0,
        fillColor: {
                linearGradient: [300, 0, 300, 400],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgba(237,230,126, 0.2)'],
                    [1, 'rgba(237,230,126, 1)']
                ]
            },
        zIndex: 0
    }, {
        data: rangesNO,
        type: 'arearange',
        lineWidth: 0,
        fillColor: {
                linearGradient: [500, 0, 500, 600],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgba(104,217,91, 0.2)'],
                    [1, 'rgba(104,217,91, 0.7)']
                ]
            },
        zIndex: 0
    }, {
        data: rangesLO,
        type: 'arearange',
        lineWidth: 0,
        fillColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 220],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgba(91,187,217, 0.2)'],
                    [1, 'rgba(91,187,217, 0.7)']
                ]
            },
        zIndex: 0
    }]
}, function (chart) {
    chart.renderer.text('EKSTREMALNA', 80, 95).css({
        fontSize: '16pt',
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0, 1)'
    }).add();
  chart.renderer.text('WYSOKA', 80, 145).css({
        fontSize: '16pt',
        color: 'rgba(237,230,126, 1)'
    }).add();
  chart.renderer.text('KOMFORTOWA', 80, 225).css({
        fontSize: '16pt',
        color: 'rgba(104,217,91, 01)'
    }).add();
  chart.renderer.text('NISKA', 80, 305).css({
        fontSize: '16pt',
        color: 'rgba(91,187,217, 1)'
    }).add();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qazopap4/1/ but this is far from what I'v expected.
I can't make linear gradient for each arearange separately.

Comment: How abour using [plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotBands) http://jsfiddle.net/pag5qgsm/ ?

Comment: Great !! You're the best. That is the thing I've searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotBands) which allows you to apply gradients.

```
yAxis: {
  plotBands: [{
    from: 60,
    to: 90,
    color: {
      linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
      stops: [
        [0, 'rgba(255,0,0, 0.2)'],
        [1, 'rgba(255,0,0, 1)']
      ]
    }
  }],
  max: 90,
  min: 20,
  title: {
    text: null
  }
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pag5qgsm